# copy a matrix and rotate an arrow matrix 90 degrees more then once in c

Tags: c

Hey I want to copy an arrow matrix to another matrix and rotate the arrow in it 90 degrees clock wise. I managed to rotate from pointing to 3 to 6 but when I try to rotate it again to 9 it goes back to 3.

I think the problem is that I need to take the whole column first from the end but unsure how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void DisplayArray2D(char arr[][7]);
void RotateArray2D(char arrRotated[][7], char arrOriginal[][7]);


void main() {
    char arr[7][7] = {
        { '*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        { '*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},     
        { '*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        { '*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
        { '*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        { '*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        { '*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
};
char arr6[7][7];
char arr9[7][7];

DisplayArray2D(arr);
RotateArray2D(arr6,arr);
DisplayArray2D(arr6);
RotateArray2D(arr9,arr6);
DisplayArray2D(arr9);

}

void DisplayArray2D(char arr[][7]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
        printf("%c",arr[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void RotateArray2D(char arrRotated[][7], char arrOriginal[][7]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            arrRotated[j][i] = arrOriginal[i][j];
        }
    }
    // DisplayArray2D(arrRotated);
}
```

Comment: " I managed to rotate from pointing to 3 to 6" well, it looks like that when you look at the programs outbut but actually you didn't.... It looks like that because the initial array is symmetric in a way the make your faulty rotate appear to work.....  Replace all elements in the last row with `'A'` and run your code.

Comment: Try this in your rotate function instead of the current code: `arrRotated[i][6-j] = arrOriginal[j][i];`

Comment: Your algorithm is equivalent to "matrix transpose" which isn't really the same thing as 90 degree rotation, but rather "90 degree rotation and then mirror the result". That is, `{A,B}, {C,D}` transposed is `{A,C}, {B,D}` but you seem to be looking for (clockwise) rotation `{C,A}, {D,B}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, your comments really helped. indeed I was missing the [6-i] in the function in order to rotate the right way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).